# How to stop C2 audit trace in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to stop the C2 Audit Trace in SQL Server?

I have used the procedure show below to stop but still the trace files (`*.trc`) is filling my disk space.

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'c2 audit mode', N'0'
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Comment: Restarted the server/instance?

Comment: What does `EXEC sys.sp_configure` show for the running value?

Comment: yes,I restarted the server after executing this procedure but still (*.trc) file filling my disk space